# Does PayPal Sandbox send emails?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Just curious, working with PayPal Sandbox works fine but I never receive any emails, neither as a sandbox seller nor as a buyer. I can just see them as "Notification" under **PayPal Developer website > Applications > Sandbox accounts > click Notifications**.

Should or should not I be receiving real emails as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sandbox environment doesn't send emails. You can just check the notifications inside your developer account only.

Comment: But I cant get the notification inside my developer acc. please advice

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox doesnot send to any email form the user,If you wanna give the detail that how much money less so you can login seller account and check that how much money less in your account same as for buyer. and also sendbox send notification in buyer and seller account.

Comment: while I order with different sandbox account I doesn't get the notification for buyer and seller account please advice.